# Changing the directory path's forward slash to backslash

Tags: java, file-io

I'm using the JFile chooser, and trying to import a pdf file but;

```
if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String fs = File.separator;
     String filelist = " "; 
     filelist = " "+chooser.getSelectedFile();
     filelist = filelist.replace("\\","/");
     File sf = new File(filelist);



 statusbar.setText("You chose " + filelist);
 System.out.println(filelist);

 PDDocument doc = null;
  try 
  {
         filelist = filelist.replace("\\","/");

    doc = PDDocument.load(filelist);
```

System.out.println(filelist); perfectly prints the desired outcome with forward slashes;

C:/Users/raz/Documents/2pg.pdf

but the doc gives an error with backslashes;
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:\Users\raz\Documents\2pg.pdf (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: Why appending the space: filelist = " "+chooser.getSelectedFile(); ?

Comment: Because, filelist is a string

Comment: If it's already returning a string then, don't append space!!! Else Have you heard of String.valueOf, or object.toString() try using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the path separator that's causing your problem, its the space at the front of the name:

`filelist = " "+chooser.getSelectedFile();`

It should just be:

`filelist = chooser.getSelectedFile();`

Comment: The filelist will give an error without it because it is a String, the problem is inside the try { } it won't work. I use the same directory as a string.

Comment: It seems to display fine, because you don't visually notice the space, but the computer notices the space and it amounts to invalid syntax. `getSelectedFile()` returns a string, theres no need for the `" "`. Try what I suggested and see.

Comment: Perfect, I got what you mean, but because filelist is a String, I did rather; ""+chooser.getSelectedFile(); Thank You!